# What is the gradle dependency for "Google Maps Mobile SDK for Work"?

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2, android-gradle-plugin, dependency-management

I'm migrating from the free Google Maps API for Android v2 to the Google Maps Mobile SDK for Work.

The documentation states that I should only replace the **gsm** package with the **m4b** package in all import statements. However, it does not explain, what dependency to add in order to let Android Studio resolve that package.

Instead I'm given a Download via Android SDK-Manager that produces no artifact for importing, but an Eclipse project with no instructions on how to proceed https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/android/

Shall I import this project as module into my own app? Isn't there any reasonable support for dependency management?

Answer (score 1):

Does not appear to have one at this time. Google Map issue for this: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7558

The way I imported it into Android Studio after downloading is:

1. In Android Studio import the AAR file of Google Maps for Work by
   File->New Module->Import existing .JAR or .AAR Package
2. Add dependencies in Gradle as:  `compile project(':google-maps-sdk-m4b')`